# Do properties always need to be declared in data: { }

Tags: vue.js

I'm getting familiar with Vue.js after having previously used AngularJS and I'd like to find if there's any way to get around explicitly declaring every data property in data { }.

In AngularJS, it was enough to declare ng-model as an HTML attribute and when the app initializes it adds them to the scope so they can be read/manipulated.

My concern is that I have a technical calculator I'm making with about 100 individual properties and declaring each property twice seems redundant.

Does Vue offer anyway to implicitly pick up the model properties without explicitly declaring them in the app data?

Example AngularJS without explicitly declaring model properties in the app:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="exampleController">
    <input ng-model="firstName" ng-change="makeName()">
    <input ng-model="lastName"  ng-change="makeName()">
    <input ng-model="fullName">
</div>
<script>
    angular.module("exampleApp", []).controller("exampleController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.makeName = function () {
            $scope.fullName = $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
        }
    });
</script>
```

More or less the same app in Vue.js:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="exampleApp">
    <input v-model="firstName" v-on:input="makeName">
    <input v-model="lastName" v-on:input="makeName">
    <input v-model="fullName">
</div>
<script>    
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#exampleApp',        
        data: {
           firstName: "",
           lastName: "",
           fullName: ""
        }, 
        methods: {
            makeName: function () {
                this.fullName = this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't you think it's a bad idea if the only place where your model is documented is basically the html? I'd suggest creating a sealed model object that you properly document using JSDoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for any 'variable' used in the HTML template, it must be declared in the JS.

While this can seem annoying when you have a lot of variables, it is important since the variable can be any one of a number of reactive things - simple variables, computed properties, methods etc. It wouldn't be possible to know what to create without also some syntax to specify what *type* of variable should be created, or to specify any default values.

In your example, `fullName` should probably be specified as a `computed` property - e.g.:

```
computed: {
  fullName: function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

This way there is no need for the v-on:input - when the `firstName` and `lastName` variables update, this will trigger `fullName` to be recalculated.

Comment: Moving the all the output properties into computed makes sense over declaring dozens and dozens of empty initializers in data{}.  At least then it'll include the actual work to calculate the value and isn't just clutter and useless typing. Thanks for the recommendation. I'll just have to grit my teeth and deal with the 20 or so empty input initializers in data{} since those aren't calculated.

Comment: I'd also recommend if you're starting out in Vue that you begin looking at the composition API in Vue3. It makes doing things like keeping data in nested data structures a lot easier to use, via `ref` and `reactive` methods.